# Is there a sleep function when using SQL Compact

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, compact-framework

I am trying to find a way of putting a pause of a few seconds into SQL being executed against an SQL Compact database.

Is there something equivalent to SQL Server's [WAITFOR function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx)?

Comment: No, there is not - but why do you need it? Process.Sleep() maybe?

Comment: @ErikEJ There is a system that takes in a series of SQL commands in order, which is having problems processing command 2 because command 1 appears to still be processing.  Unfortunately I don't have the ability to change the code that's processing the commands.